# Doctrine 2: Convert mapping to YAML with namespace?

Tags: namespaces, doctrine-orm, command-line-interface

I am using Doctrine 2, and a MySQL back end. I am running a CLI command to analyze the the schema and produce YML files. I am using the following CLI command.

```
 php ./doctrine.php orm:convert-mapping --verbose --force --from-database yml tmp_yaml
```

I then do some processing on the YAML files, and then have Doctrine create entity files from them. However, we need the entities to be in a particular namespace. Right now I just process the resulting entity .php files, but that is a really bad way to do it.

How can I have Doctrine create YAML's with our namespace. If that is not possible, how can I have Doctrine create entities that are in our namespace?

Thanks!!! -Don!

Answer (score 0):

[In the docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/yaml-mapping.html#example) they say to name the YAML file and the root element with the full name of the entity class, including the namespace (separated by `.` instead of `\`)

> Be aware that class-names specified in the YAML files should be fully qualified.

That should be it.

Comment: I am running this process from the CLI. It looks like you are implying we write a whole mapping processor application. How do we do this from the CLI?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the part about generating from the DB Schema. If you want to use YAML for your entity config, I would generate your YAML *once* and rename the files and root elements to match namespaces. Now the YAML files become the "master" copy. From that point on, generate your entities and schema from your YAML files.

Comment: Alternatively, how do I perform the above operation via code, rather than the CLI?